# Clicar em classe com o mesmo nome usando selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Estou tentando fazer uma automatização em python usando o Selenium no entanto n'ao estou conseguindo clicar nos elementos restantes pois todos eles tem a mesma classe.

esse é o código que faz o clique no elemento

```
Ao_Vivo = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ovm-FixtureDetailsTwoWay_Wrapper"]')
Ao_Vivo.click()
```

eu já tentei usar ele das seguintes formas

assim

```
Ao_Vivo = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ovm-FixtureDetailsTwoWay_Wrapper"]')[2]
Ao_Vivo.click()
```

e assim

```
    Ao_Vivo = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ovm-FixtureDetailsTwoWay_Wrapper"][2]')
    Ao_Vivo.click()
```

mas acabou dando erro.

Este é o html da pagina

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer.

esse é o erro que apresenta

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: *...mas acabou dando erro....* Mas que erro?

Comment: fala que a classe nao existe

Comment: Somos técnicos de TI. Por favor [edit] a pergunta e adicione a mensagem de erro completa.

Comment: adicionei a imagem do erro

Comment: Ja tentou usar o `find_elements_by_xpath()`? Outro problema pode ser que o elemento ainda não esteja completamente carregado, tenta primeiro um `time.sleep(5)` antes de buscar o elemento.

Comment: Na verdade o primeiro elemento ele encontra, o problema são os outros que ele não encontra de forma automática.

Comment: Eu já deixei o tempo pra carregar a página e mesmo assim não obtive êxito

Comment: O find_elements_by_xpath() também não funcionou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tudo bem? Já passei por um problema similar e procurei bastante informação para tentar encontrar uma resposta pra isso. O que eu encontrei e o que eu percebi é que não é muito saudável utilizar `find_elements` com o `XPATH` e nem com o `CSS_SELECTOR`, não faz sentido encontrar múltiplos elementos com apenas um caminho, certo?

Normalmente utilizo o `find_elements` junto com o `class_name`, `id` e `name`. Acredito que a melhor solução para o seu problema seja utilizar o class_name, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
Ao_Vivo = navegador.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ovm-FixtureDetailsTwoWay_Wrapper')
```

O selenium vai retornar uma lista com todos os elementos que foram encontrados a class_name ovm-FixtureDetailsTwoWay_Wrapper. Agora é só seguir a lógica de uma lista, caso queria chamar o segundo elemento da lista é colocar um `Ao_Vivo[1]` (Lembrando uma lista sempre começa com o primeiro valor sendo 0).

Uma outra coisa é que quase sempre a função `.click` do selenium não funciona em alguns elementos não clicáveis, como por exemplo uma div. Se você encontrar uma div que que deseja clicar e não conseguem e sempre aparece o erro "element not interactable", é só usar o código abaixo:

```
navegado.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", AQUI_FICA_O_ELEMENTO_QUE_VAI_SER_CLICADO)
```

Um resumo de como seu código poderia ficar:

```
Ao_Vivo = navegador.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ovm-FixtureDetailsTwoWay_Wrapper')

navegado.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Ao_Vivo[2])
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado